# Jupyter Notebook error-ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium

This is the error message I am getting after running the code in Jupyter Notebook.

If I write pip install selenium its is saying pip not found

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from selenium import webdriver
      2 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
      3 import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Comment: Are you using Anaconda as your distribution? You may want to try `%conda install selenium` in a cell in your notebook if you are mostly using Anaconda/conda/mamba as your package manager. Mixing pip and conda can often lead to obscure environment issues and in that case pip is best reserved for when there isn't an Anaconda/conda option for installation. However, the same holds true if you are primarily only using `pip` to manage your packages. You'd do best by keeping things working to stick with `pip` (`%pip` if you are running it inside a notebook cell!) and only `pip` as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` isn't found, it could be `pip3`.

Note that you have to run pip in a terminal, not in Jupyter.

If that doesn't work, you may need to install pip: try the Windows or Mac installer, and select pip, or on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: @bobth'-' You can run `pip` in Jupyter cells. In fact using the new magics for `pip` and `conda` inside cells in a Jupyter notebook can often insure your are installing to the correct environment backing the notebook. Please see here to learn more about new magic commands added a few years ago [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: See my comments below F. Hoque's answer for more information as well.